# jquery.fullPage.js in joomla template

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, fullpage.js

Hi every one im very new with using javascript and i cant get this jquery.fullpage.js scroll function to work, https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs
and i have no idea how i should install it.

my code:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <link href="/mysite/css/jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <script src="/mysite/js/jquery.fullPage.js">
   </head>
   <body>
     <div class="section active">
       MYCONTENT
     </div>
     <div class="section">
       MYCONTENT
     </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Are you doing this in Joomla? You need to give a few more details.

Comment: You'd be better off creating a template with a structure similar to the above.

Comment: Are you sure this is part of Joomla?

Answer (score 1):

I have been trixing with this for a few hours and its easy

This is my joomla template! (example)

```
 <head>
 //here you put the code that gets the source files for fullpage.js  which you find on the github link//
 </head>

 <body>
 //here is your body and it probably have tons of <div> elements in it, in different levels like this:
 <div>
    <div>
      <div>
     //here you can for example find a line of php that renders a module.
     </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

The thing i did wrong when i tried to implement fullpage.js to my joomla site was that i where putting the **section class** to a div that was not in level 2 after the body tag

What i want to explain with that is:

```
 <body>
 <div id="fullpag <<-this is where fullpage starts">
    <div class="section" >
    YOUR CONTENT
    </div>
 </div>
```

The div with the id fullpage should always start in the first level and the section always in the second level after the body tag, i have no real name for what i call levels but i hope everyone understands.